# Livewire - Array as query string

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm using array as my query string, but can I reformat this query string?
instead of name of parameter and index, I want the values are separated by coma

so instead of
`topic[0]=economic&topic[1]=politic`

it will be `topic=economic,politic`

how to do that?